# get the first letter of every word inside li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to get all the initials of li and display it or replace the value of li instead? I have a sample js found in the net which gets all the initials of every word but i want it to replace it and get the value of my li instead.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Alpha</li>
    <li>Beta</li>
    <li>Charlie</li>
    <li>Charlie Delta Omega Lima Egg</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var text = '';
var arr = "Java Script Object Notation".split(' ');
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    text += arr[i].substr(0,1)
}    
alert(text);
```

OUTPUT:

```
    <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
<li>CHOLE</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: you can do it in css using :first-letter to reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```js
$(function () {
  $("li").html(function (i, v) {
    return v.trim().split(" ").map(function (obj) {
      return obj.substr(0, 1);
    }).join("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Alpha Beta</li>
  <li>Beta</li>
  <li>Charlie</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you use the form of `html()` that takes a function, then don't call `html()` again to obtain the current value -- it is already passed as the second argument to your function.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yeah, sorry, forgot. Check the updated answer. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: will this work if my li contains for example "Alpha Beta" the output should be "AB"

Comment: @MichaelPon No. But wait. Lemme do it for you.

Comment: @MichaelPon See the updated answer. Use `map()` function for that.

Comment: Recommend you use `.text()` rather than `.html()` in this case as you're working with the text value.  You'll get some unexpected results if you use happen to included nested tags, eg `<li><a>Apha</a></li>` or `<li><span class='icon'></span>text with icon</li>`

Comment: I have some problems with the codes i was wondering if I already converted the value i want it to go back when I click a button. like a toggle on off with different value.

Comment: Like what? @MichaelPon? Can yo uexplain?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `text` method, to get the `innerText` of each of the `li` element and then you can replace it by the first letter.

Use `trim` as if the text contains leading spaces, space will be shown.

To get the first letter of each of the word, you can split it by spaces, map it then get the first letter using substring method. And finally the returned array can be joined by empty space to concat the array elements.

```js
$('ul li').text(function(i, old) {
  return old.trim().split(/\s+/).map(function(e, i) {
    return e.substr(0, 1);
  }).join('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Alpha Beta</li>
  <li>Beta</li>
  <li>Charlie</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque, pariatur, aperiam! Nesciunt laudantium amet nulla veritatis doloremque voluptate enim fugiat, ad voluptas, dolor non eum quam est eveniet libero consequuntur.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: will this work if my li contains for example "Alpha Beta" the output should be "AB"

Comment: @MichaelPon Yes, it'll now

Answer (score 0):

This is done by regex also.

```js
$('ul li').text(function(i, old) {
 return old.trim().split(/\s+/).map(function(e, i) {
  return e.match(/\S/i);
 }).join("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Alpha</li>
  <li>Beta</li>
  <li>Charlie</li>
  <li>Alpha Beta</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use `\S` instead of `[a-z]`, if the text starts with special symbol this will not wokr

Comment: @PraveenKumar Just another option

Comment: will this work if my li contains for example "Alpha Beta" the output should be "AB"

Answer (score 0):

I know you've tagged `jQuery` in your question, but as soon as someone else could prefer a vanilla Javascript version, it's below:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul li'), (item, i) => {
    item.textContent = item.textContent.split(' ').map(x => x.slice(0, 1)).join('');
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Alpha</li>
  <li>Beta</li>
  <li>Charlie</li>
  <li>Charlie Delta Omega Lima Egg</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace the value of your `li`s, you can use `.text()`.  If you only want the first letter, then forget the js you found and use `trim` and `.substr` :

```
$("li")
    .text(function(i,txt) { 
        return txt.trim().substr(0,1); 
    })
```

this gets all the `li`s, passes the current text and replaces it by removing any spaces then taking the first letter.

If you want to build an acronym as implied by the question title and text (but not the [original] example) then you can use a `regexp`, depending on how you want to build your acronym:

```
$("#leadingspace li").text(function(i,txt) { return txt.match(/\b\w/g).join("") })

$("#caps li").text(function(i,txt) { return txt.match(/[A-Z]/g).join("") })

$("#spacescaps li").text(function(i,txt) { return txt.match(/\b[A-Z]/g).join("") })

$("#firstonly li").text(function(i,txt) { return txt.trim().substr(0,1); })
```

source

```
<ul id='leadingspace'>
    <li>JavaScript Object Notification</li>
</ul>

<ul id='caps'>
    <li>JavaScript Object Notification</li>
</ul>

<ul id='spacescaps'>
    <li>Laugh Out really Loud</li>
</ul>

<ul id='firstonly'>
    <li>Alpha Beta</li>
    <li>Beta</li>
</ul>
```

result

```
JON
JSON
LOL
A
B
```

jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9yqqnhpx/) including the first-letter only